# Handling click events on Capacitor Local Notifications when the app is closed

Tags: capacitor, quasar, localnotification, capacitor-plugin

I'm encountering an issue within my app that utilizes Capacitor with Quasar. We're utilizing the *@capacitor/local-notifications* plugin to handle local notifications, and we have a method that gets triggered when the notification is clicked, using the following listener:

```
await LocalNotifications.addListener('localNotificationActionPerformed', handleLocalNotificationAction);
```

However, when the app is closed (not in the foreground), this listener obviously doesn't fire. We're in need of a way to execute a method upon notification click, such as opening the app at a specific URL or performing a certain action even if the app is closed.

We've tried some things, like:

- Calling the listener right after the app boot;
- Use some kind of background service to keep the listener working;

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some tries I figured out how to solve my problem. Basically the listener was being called, but the method that I used to handle had some dependencies that were not loaded (in my case it was Vue Router).

I just added a retry method that will wait the boot time and try again and it turned out to be working!

I'll post my function, maybe it can help someone:

```
const openAccordingToPlatform = async (params) => {
  if (Platform.is.capacitor) {
    pushWithRetry(params);
    return;
  }

  const url = router().resolve(params).href;
  openOnNewTab(url);
};
```